# Dynamic loading of external javascript

Tags: javascript, angularjs, dynamic

I am currently working on changing the Angular Bootstrap Datepicker Language.
I already saw some answers such as linking to the locale(s). But what I want to have is
everytime I change the language, which I have a translation. The language of datepicker should also change.

I think I can achieve this by loading the angular locale

like

```
<script type ="text/javascript" src ="js/angular-locale_de-de.js"></script>
```

what I want to do is to change the src dynamically everytime I change the language so the Angular Calendar's language would also update.

Example, when I click the language "Espaniol", the src would change to 'js/angular-locale_es-es.js"
french to "js/angular-locale_fr-fr.js"
etc.

I have a code here

this is the function

```
 function loadjscssfile(filename) {
        var fileRef = document.createElement('script');
        fileRef.setAttribute("type", "text/javascript");
        fileRef.setAttribute("src", filename);

        if (typeof fileRef != "undefined") {
            document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0].appendChild(fileRef);
        }


    }
```

however, its no working. please do help me with this thank you!
Thanks!

Comment: Are you sure that the javascript file will be loaded again when you change the src attribute ?  You can put an `alert` inside the scripts to be sure they are being loaded...

Comment: Hello Vitor, I already did that, it's not loading. I also called the function in my ng-click function but still nothing happened.

Comment: I mean the alert is working, however the script is not loaded

Comment: Did you try this?http://www.javascriptkit.com/javatutors/loadjavascriptcss2.shtml#demotable

Comment: That's the code I used, it loads my alert, however the language does not change.